# Call a function in viewcontroller with parameter from another class

Tags: swift, notificationcenter

I have a class named CameraManager. It inherits from  `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

In `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])`  I want to call `setImageInImageView(image:UIImage)` function that is in viewcontroller and pass the photo taked by user to it.

Here is my wrong code in CameraManager class.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    ViewController.setImageToImageView(theImage: chosenImage) // wrong code
}
```

I know I can set the photo in different ways, like create an outlet to imageview in my CameraManager class, or viewcontroller inherits `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

But I want do this in separated class. After some searches I found NotificationCenter, but it's complex for a swift beginner like me and there is few resources in swift 3 with passing parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your opened `ViewController` object to `CameraManager` class and in `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])` you can `openViewControllerObject.setImageToImageView(theImage: chosenImage)`.

Comment: Thanks. I pass the ViewController to CameraManager initializer and set it to a variable in the CameraManager that type is ViewController  and it works. Can you explain me the way using notification center?

Comment: My suggestion to you is that don't use Notification for this purpose. Instead you can use closure as completion handler. Here closure will be the best approach.

Comment: It is a pleasure for me that I helped to solve your problem. Now please mark and upvote my answer so it will be helpful to others.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot upvote because my reputation is under 15.